# Having the site title be aligned over multiple lines

Tags: css

In my site the title is very long so that its appearing in two lines but then 2nd line is not aligned. How can I use css to align both lines together?

An example can be viewed [here](http://pligg.marsgibson.info/story.php?title=when-i-was-responsible-for-all-the-pcs-in-a-large-studio-i-learned-that-i-needed-to-carry-a-recovery-disk-at-all-times-)

Comment: Add the star image in span to background of H2 & delete that span. An also remove negative top margin from subtext1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a style to float the avatar to the left. Here is an example:

```
#ls_avatar-0 {
float: left;
}
```

Also, you may want to clear the float to prevent the region from collapsing, like this:

```
.subtext1 {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Yes it works
but it disturbs the "posted by" (below the title) on the main page
see the main page (second story)
http://pligg.marsgibson.info
posted by must be slightly above in the second story
appreciate your help